# How to access geolocation data of a tweet?

Tags: twitter, geolocation

I want to see the geolocation data of my previous tweets. Unfortunately, I didn't find the way to do it. Is it possible, and how?

Comment: @pnuts: of course, yes

Comment: Are you trying to view them straight from Twitter or a Twitter client, or do you mean by using the Twitter API?

Comment: @freginold the former: straight from Twitter; or any other *simple* solution

Comment: Do you have an example tweet that you're sure has geolocation data attached to it?

Comment: @freginold https://imgur.com/5GPQ38Q

Comment: @tic That image just shows the icon; do you have a link to a tweet that you're sure has geolocation data that should be showing?

Comment: choose one as desired https://twitter.com/search?q=geocode%3A40.709%2C-74.011%2C.1km&src=typd

Answer (score 1):

The tweet contains geolocation data only if the app that created the tweet included it. Many camera apps do this but most others don't. Users may also have disabled GPS.

My app [TweetsToRSS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vsubhash.droid.tweetstorss) displays this whenever geolocation data is available in the tweet. The app generates RSS data for rss feed readers. It also generates plain HTML output that can be viewed in any browser. There is a desktop version of this app too.

[image: TweetsToRSS for Android displays geolocation data].